# Can't find first-party Microsoft applications when trying to get servicePrincipal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I'm encountering the following scenario:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in

I see in the sign in reports some sign ins with first-party Microsoft applications.
For example, one of the sign in logs have the following fields:

`"appId": "89bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7",`

`"appDisplayName": "Office365 Shell WCSS-Client",`

which is one of the apps mentioned in this document.

The problem I'm facing, is that I can't get this app when I use the "get service principal" command\api. It's not found, and I also can't find it when I'm using the "list service principal" command and trying to filter by name or app id.

This happens in other first party apps as well, they are not found.
I don't understand how it's possible that I see them in the sign in logs, but I can't find them.

Anyone have any idea how can I find them?

I tried using the get serivcePrincipal api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters), I can't see it there, nor in the list servicePrincipals api.

Answer (score 1):

According to this **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in#:%7E:text=Azure%20AD%20logs.-,Note,-First-party%20Microsoft)**,

> First-party Microsoft applications **don't** always result in a **service principal** that's created in your tenant. But you can still see these applications in your sign-in reports.

In my tenant, I too found **sign-ins** with first-party Microsoft application named `Office365 Shell WCSS-Client` like this:

[image]

I checked the same in Portal by filtering **Microsoft Applications** in Enterprise Applications tab and by running below PowerShell command too but **no results**:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Office365 Shell WCSS-Client'" | fl *
```

[image]

**Graph API:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='89bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7')
```

[image]

When I tried to check for another first-party app like `Office 365 Search Service`, I got the **results** successfully as below:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Office 365 Search Service'" | fl *
```

[image]

**Graph API:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='66a88757-258c-4c72-893c-3e8bed4d6899')
```

[image]

> Note that, some of the first-party apps **do not show up** in either UI or PowerShell/CLI or Graph API but you can still see their sign-in reports.

To **confirm** that, you can check similar issue answered in this [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1346725/why-do-some-microsoft-applications-have-a-service) by [**Vasil Michev-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/michev/)